# How to change string value using firebase

Tags: android, string, firebase

I am using WebView inside my application and I used a String called web_url inside the 'webView.loadUrl' line. Now I want to the change the String web_url address from the internet to a specific one which can't be predicted before completely building the app.

So I would like to know what is the best method to change string value, whether using Firebase or something else.

Any replies are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firebase Remote Config in a similar situation where I want to change some of my app settings remotely on the fly.

From the docs:

> Firebase Remote Config is a cloud service that lets you change the behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to download an app update. When using Remote Config, you create in-app default values that control the behavior and appearance of your app. Then, you can later use the Firebase console to override in-app default values

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseRef.child("message").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());  //prints "Do you have data? Firebase."
  }
  @Override public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) { }
});
```

[Firebase's quickstart guide for Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html)